# Artificially generate key events in other programs

Tags: c#, media-player, keyevent, kinect

Can a C# program that has focus artificially generate a key event that will be handled by another open application?

For those who are curious, this is why I'm asking:

I'm currently working on a demo/mockup for a design idea for a gesture based media player, using the Kinect as a primary input device. This is something I decided to do on as a favor, and it neither needs nor deserves a ton of my time as far as programming goes.

So to speed things along, I'm using the FAAST tool which you can use to easily bind key events to certain gestures. So, you turn on this program, tell it what key maps to what gesture, then when you make the gesture the key is registered as pressed by the current application.

What I would like to create is a go-between that will display a simple GUI that I'll display to the audience. At a certain point, the user will make the "select" gesture, and I want music to start playing in an open media player. So, I would check their place in the menu hierarchy, see that they've selected "music" based on some key I choose to arbitrarily mean select, then generate a key event with the MediaPlayPause key.

Comment: You want to interact with the menu in the other application, or the menu will be in your application? It's fairly trivial to send an event to another window, but determining the state of another application is much harder.

Answer (score 1):

It requires a little p/invoke work to do from C# but it's not complicated. You'll use the [FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow) API to get an hWnd for the target program, then the [PostMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/PostMessage.html) API to send key events:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private const UInt32 WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

public static void SendSelect(IntPtr HWnd)
{
    PostMessage(HWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter), 0);
}
```